# How to split this XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, xml

Not a big XML expert here... Say I have an Xml node from a larger doc that looks something like this:

```
<TopLevel>
   <Element1>...</Element1>
   <Element2>...</Element2>
   <Element3>
      <Sub1>abc</Sub1>
      <Sub2>def</Sub2>
   </Element3>
   <Element3>
      <Sub1>ghi</Sub1>
      <Sub2>jkl</Sub2>
   </Element3>
   <Element3>
      <Sub1>mno</Sub1>
      <Sub2>pqr</Sub2>
   </Element3>
</TopLevel>
```

(Element3 can repeat an unlimited amount of times)
I want to wind up with three nodes, like this:

```
<TopLevel>
   <Element1>...</Element1>
   <Element2>...</Element2>
   <Element3>
      <Sub1>abc</Sub1>
      <Sub2>def</Sub2>
   </Element3>
</TopLevel>
<TopLevel>
   <Element1>...</Element1>
   <Element2>...</Element2>
   <Element3>
      <Sub1>ghi</Sub1>
      <Sub2>jkl</Sub2>
   </Element3>
</TopLevel>
<TopLevel>
   <Element1>...</Element1>
   <Element2>...</Element2>
   <Element3>
      <Sub1>mno</Sub1>
      <Sub2>pqr</Sub2>
   </Element3>
</TopLevel>
```

If I knew Element3 could only repeat twice I'd just clone the node, remove the first instance from the original node, remove the second instance from the cloned node and InsertAfter, but I'm not sure how to do it for an unknown number of elements...

Thanks!

Comment: Where comes the final content of `<Sub1>...</Sub1>` from first Element3 or from Last? or what?

Comment: I edited the xml above to make it more clear.

Comment: You should make it much more clearer what your requirements are.  So you want a `TopLevel` node for each `Element3` that occurs with copies of every other element?

Comment: Not sure how to make it any more clear than the before and after shown above (and that's not meant in a sarcastic tone...)... I'll start with a single TopLevel node that contains a single Element1, a single Element2, and one or more Element3. The output should end up with the same number of TopLevel nodes that there were Element3 nodes. Each new TopLevel node will contain the same info that was in the original Element1 and Element2 (since those don't repeat), and a single Element3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML standard only allows a single top level node, so you will need a wrapper around all of your `<TopLevel>`. Depending on what is consuming your output that may or may not matter.

```
XDocument input; //Fill this in somehow
XElement top = input.Element("TopLevel");
XElement elem1 = top.Element("Element1");
XElement elem2 = top.Element("Element2");
XDocument output = new XDocument(); //You may need to do additional initialization here
foreach (XElement elem3 in top.Elements("Element3");
{
    output.Add(new XElement("TopLevel", elem1, elem2, elem3));
}
```

It has been a while since I have generated output files, so I am sorry if my syntax isn't 100% correct.

Comment: Actually TopLevel is a child node of a larger document, so that's not an issue. I didn't show the rest of the document for brevity.

Answer (score 2):

If XSLT is an option for you, then the following stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/TopLevel">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Element3"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Element3">
        <TopLevel>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../Element1|../Element2"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        </TopLevel>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the following output (which I formatted):

```
<root>
    <TopLevel>
        <Element1>...</Element1>
        <Element2>...</Element2>
        <Element3>
      <Sub1>abc</Sub1>
      <Sub2>def</Sub2>
        </Element3>
    </TopLevel>
    <TopLevel>
        <Element1>...</Element1>
        <Element2>...</Element2>
        <Element3>
      <Sub1>ghi</Sub1>
      <Sub2>jkl</Sub2>
        </Element3>
    </TopLevel>
    <TopLevel>
        <Element1>...</Element1>
        <Element2>...</Element2>
        <Element3>
      <Sub1>...</Sub1>
      <Sub2>...</Sub2>
        </Element3>
    </TopLevel>
</root>
```

The output that you give is a document fragment; I added a `root` element so that it could be loaded as a regular document.  But XSLT will emit this without the root element as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
string fromXml = 
@"
    <TopLevel>
        <Element1>...</Element1>
        <Element2>...</Element2>
        <Element3>
            <Sub1>abc</Sub1>
            <Sub2>def</Sub2>
        </Element3>
        <Element3>
            <Sub1>ghi</Sub1>
            <Sub2>jkl</Sub2>
        </Element3>
        <Element3>
            <Sub1>...</Sub1>
            <Sub2>...</Sub2>
        </Element3>
    </TopLevel>
";

XElement from = XElement.Parse(fromXml);
XElement root = new XElement("Root");
foreach (var node in from.Descendants("Element3"))
{
    XElement toplevel = new XElement("TopLevel");
    toplevel.Add(from.Element("Element1"));
    toplevel.Add(from.Element("Element2"));
    toplevel.Add(node);
    root.Add(toplevel);
}
var final = root.Nodes().Aggregate("",((s,n)=>s+=n.ToString()+"\n"));
```

Comment: @BillOsuch Argh, who removed it from `System.Linq` without any warning.

Comment: My bad, wasn't working with Linq namespace, just standard Xml.... haven't messed with Linq before